# Storing to a reference table with a foreign key (LARAVEL 5.2)

Tags: laravel-5, foreign-keys, relational-database

I just can't figure it out, and I'm getting mad.

I have 2 tables: Projects, Galleries

In the project table I have these fields: Title, Description, Gallery(multiupload)

the Galleries table is a reference table that stores project IDs and file names of images

I read that the best way to store an array of values that belong to a record is setting a reference table that preserves the relation between these values and the record ID.

This is my actual config:

I set my Gallery model

```
class Gallery extends Model
{
    public function project()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
    } 
}
```

I set my Project model

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function gallery()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gallery');
    } 
}
```

on my project controller...

```
$post = new Project;
$post->title = $data->title;
$post->save();
```

Now I should do the actual relation. So store the filenames into the image_name column in the galleries table, and the project ID (just generated creating the current project) into the project_id column in the galleries table as well...

I have $filenames which is the array that contains the filenames.. that has to be stored in the reference table

Answer (score 0):

Project belongs to gallery, so in your case it must to contain at least 3 columns: `id`, `image_name`, and `project_id` (no id_project)

Then if `$filename` array contains filenames, and $post is instance of `$gallery` just do this:

```
foreach($filename as $file)
    $post->gallery()->create(['image_name' => $file]);
```

this will create as many new projects related to `$post` gallery as many items contains your `$filename` array.

Tiny hint: rename your `project()` relation method to `projects()` - is will be easier to understand what can it contain. Current name suggest only one project.

Comment: $filename just contains the array of filenames of selected images [banana.jpg, apple.jpg, peach.jpg]... I need to store those data in separate rows with the project ID in the project_id column (foreign key)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I always get "MassAssignmentException" using create. Just a clarification, in that controller I'm saving a project that has images.. so the project and its fields are correctly stored, but the images (file names), need to be stored in another table that keeps the reference between projects ID and filenames. I want to save them in the galleries table and save the project ID they belong to as well

Comment: I thought that your project model (and table) stores only filenames. If there are any other informations that we need (other related models or something else that may be important), add it to your question. I think you have another model "File' for files table. And that the information you didn;t posted before.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was much easier than I though

I just can't figure it out, and I'm getting mad.

I have 2 tables: Projects, Galleries

In the project table I have these fields: Title, Description, Gallery(multiupload)

the Galleries table is a reference table that stores project IDs and file names of images

I read that the best way to store an array of values that belong to a record is setting a reference table that preserves the relation between these values and the record ID.

This is my actual config:

I set my Gallery model

```
class Gallery extends Model
{
    // you must indicate the DB fields that will be used by the create method
    protected $fillable = ['project_id', 'image_path'];
}
```

I set my Project model

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function gallery()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Gallery');
    } 
}
```

my project controller...

```
$post = new Project;
$post->title = $data->title;
$post->description = $data->description;
$post->client = $data->client;
$post->save();

$postGallery = new Gallery;

// $images is an array        
$images = $data->file('gallery');

foreach($images as $key => $image) {

    $filename =  'banana.jpg'

    $postGallery->create(['image_path' => $filename, 'project_id' => $data->id]);
}
```